# Audio not working on Debian Jessie

Tags: debian, audio

I have recently installed Debian Jessie with KDE on an Asus X556UB, and the audio is not working at all.

I can see and adjust the volume controls with KMix, but it has no effect.

When I tried alsactl init, I got the following message:

```
No protocol specified
xcb_connection_has_error() returned true
Found hardware: "HDA-Intel" "Intel ID 2809" "HDA:10ec0255,10431c7d,00100002 HDA:80862809,80860101,00100000" "0x1043" "0x1c7d
```

When I tried to play a WAV file as root with mplayer, I got the following output:

```
Detected file format: WAV / WAVE (Waveform Audio) (libavformat)
[lavf] stream 0: audio (pcm_u8), -aid 0
Load subtitles in <FOLDER>
Selected audio codec: Uncompressed PCM [pcm]
AUDIO: 22050 Hz, 1 ch, u8, 176.4 kbit/100.00% (ratio: 22050->22050)
No protocol specified
xcb_connection_has_error() returned true
AO: [pulse] Init failed: Access denied
No protocol specified
xcb_connection_has_error() returned true
No protocol specified
xcb_connection_has_error() returned true
[AO_ALSA] alsa-lib: pulse.c:243:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Access denied

[AO_ALSA] Playback open error: Connection refused
[AO OSS] audio_setup: Can't open audio device /dev/dsp: No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
[JACK] cannot open server
[AO SDL] Samplerate: 22050Hz Channels: Mono Format u8
No protocol specified
xcb_connection_has_error() returned true
No protocol specified
xcb_connection_has_error() returned true
[AO_ALSA] alsa-lib: pulse.c:243:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Access denied

[AO SDL] Unable to open audio: No available audio device
AO: [null] 22050Hz 1ch u8 (1 bytes per sample)
```

Could anyone please help me figure out what's wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: as root run `gpasswd -a your_username audio`

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but my user was already in the audio group, and sound doesn't work for root either.

Comment: try the answer of Stephen Kitt from here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/284147/153195 , run `apt-cache search linux-image` to find out the right linux-image

Comment: I tried installig it, but I got lots of error messages.

Comment: Tried to install a newer image (4.7), got too many errors... Couldn't even start X. SoI had to reinstall the old one.

Comment: You can boot the old one from the " advanced option for Debian GNU:/linux"  of Grub

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've fixed it!

What I did was add the following line to `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=pch position_fix=1
```

This was after having installed the `firmware-intel-sound`  package.

But that alone was not enough. I had to run **alsamixer** and select the Intel sound card (instead of 'default', which didn't work).

Thanks to everyone for your suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in [this thread](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=105722) then you might try adding the following to the bottom of `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`

```
options snd-hda-intel model=generic
```

If that file does not exist, just create it and let it contain just that line.

Comment: I'm afraidthat didn't work.I tried another suggestion on that thread and attempted to install the Realtek HDA driver, but I got the following errorwhile compiling: Rt-Linux-HDaudio-5.18/alsa-driver-RTv5.18/alsa/acore/pcm_native.c:1647:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘fget_light’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]